# Variadic Template in VS 2012 (Visual C++ November 2012 CTP)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

I installed [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) and created a C++ console project. I wrote this in

```
template<typename T>
void Test(T value){
}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Test(T value, Args... args){
    Test(value);
    Test(args...);
}

int main(){
    Test(1,2,3);
}
```

Then I pressed F6 to build in the IDE. I got this error on line 4

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'
```

The compile list "variadic templates" so I believe this should work. I do understand intellisense may be incorrect however the 'compiler' should work. Can I not build from the IDE? Do I have to enable something somewhere? `int i{4};` doesn't seem to work either and I am sure thats valid uniform initialization.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the Project Properties, make sure to select the **Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP**:

[image: Toolchain]

The new toolchain does not replace the existing Visual C++ 2012 toolchain, and it is not enabled by default.  It's installed side-by-side with the existing toolchain.

If you select the new toolchain, your program will compiler without error.

Comment: Thanks James. Wow you even made a screenshot

Comment: VS2012 Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 does still not compile the sample from the question, despite selecting "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" as Platform Toolset.

Comment: @mloskot:  The v110 toolset does not support variadic templates and never will.  You either need to use the November CTP (linked in the question) or, preferably, the newly-released Visual Studio 2013 Preview.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I've never used VS2012 CTP and I've got confused by the 2012. The actual toolset there is v120, indeed. Thanks!