# Error with variadic templates with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates

I have the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov20..), but when I attempt to use variadic templates, I get this error:

```
error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand
```

Are they even supported yet? I've properly set to use the new toolchain from the project options and everything...

```
  template<typename... T>
  void Event<T...>::operator()(T... args)
  {
   for(uint i = 0; i < _listHandlers.Size(); i++)
   {
    (_listHandlers)[i](args...);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, they're supported in the CTP, as evident by the terminology used in the error. We need code to see why there's an error.

Comment: I added source to the question,is there something wrong with the way I'm using it?

Comment: @Bogomil that above source clearly won't compile, as it is incomplete.  Post a http://sscce.org/ and point out which line is generating the error.

Comment: the error is on line (_listHandlers)[i](args...); and 'args' also gives "identifier not found"

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-contained example that should compile on its own but does not?

Answer (score 2):

Did you pick it from Project Properties?

Check [Variadic Template in VS 2012 (Visual C++ November 2012 CTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp).

It works fine on my computer.