# How to specialize a class template for a tuple when variadic template arguments are not supported?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tuples, template-specialization

I have a class template

```
template<class T>
class A
{...};
```

and I want to specialize it when T is a tuple. I think I can do this

```
template<class Args...>
class A<std::tuple<Args...>>
{...};
```

However, my compiler doesn't support variadic template arguments, how to do it?

Comment: How does your compiler support tuples if it doesn't support variadic templates? That's what you have to immitate.

Comment: Are you using VS 2012? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp

Comment: I am using VC2012 with VC11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specialize it for tuples of every different arity:

```
// explicit specialization for 0-element tuples
template<>
class A<std::tuple<>>
{...};

// partial specialization for 1-element tuples
template<class Arg>
class A<std::tuple<Arg>>
{...};

// partial specialization for 2-element tuples
template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
class A<std::tuple<Arg0, Arg1>>
{...};
```

... and so on, up to whatever maximum number of tuple elements you need to support.