# How to specialize a class template for a tuple by using variadic template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, tuples

How to specialize a class template for a tuple? I try the following but failed. I am using VC Compiler Nov 2012 CTP which support variadic template arguments.

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
   void f() {}
};

template<class... Args>
struct A<tuple<Args...>>
{
   void g() {}
};
```

I try

```
A<tuple<int, float>> a;
a.g(); // error error C2039: 'g' : is not a member of 
//'A<std::tuple<int,float,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>
```

Thanks to yngum. It might be a VC compiler bug. If so, how to work around?

Comment: Compiler error. `error C2039: 'g' : is not a member of 'A<std::tuple<int,float,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>>`

Comment: @yngum Yes. But it doesn't work on VC CTP compiler. Is this a bug for the compiler?

Comment: @user1899020 VC doesn't like variadic template, most likely a bug.

Comment: Retagging because it's a platform-specific bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler-bug. As a work-around, simply add the 2-parameter specialization

```
template<class Arg0, class Arg1>
struct A< std::tuple<Arg0, Arg1> >
{
   void g() {}
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/RKzs).

Yes, you'll have to do this for as many parameters as your code is likely to use. Or, you could try [**VS 2013 RC**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads) which is likely to have fixed this bug.

**Update**: I now see that you asked [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140519/819272) about the work-arounds. The same solution was posted there.