# How do I std::bind with more than 4 placeholders in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to bind a member to store a function object outside of the class instance. Howeber, in VS2012 this only works up to `placeholders::_4`, then it starts popping up with errors. Take this for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
    public:
    int method(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e)
    {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<int (int,int,int,int,int)> obj;
    A a;

    // error: no instance of overloaded function "std::bind" matches the argument list
    obj = std::bind(&A::method,&a,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5); 

    std::cout << obj(1,2,3,4,5);

   return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2 but causes the above-mentioned error in Visual Studio 2012. Are there any workarounds, is this a bug in VC++ or am I doing something dodgy here?

Comment: MSVS2013 just has been released. Just use it.

Comment: The code compiles just fine with VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

Since Visual Studiio does not support variadic templates this is solved by a define.

You can set a define `_VARIADIC_MAX` to the amount of params you need. Do this in your projects settings to that it is set before any system headers are included.

But keep in mind that setting this value to a large number will increase compile times.

Comment: Actually, [it appears to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13238408/501250) -- just not with the default toolset.

Comment: @cdhowie, I think VS2013's are somewhat better as well. The CTP's were quite buggy.

Comment: how do I set it in the project settings? I tried adding `_VARIADIC_MAX 6` but it didn't like it...

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be to use a lambda instead like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
public:
    int method(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
    {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int, int, int, int, int)> obj;
    A a;

    obj = [&a](int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){return a.method(b,c,d,e,f); };

    std::cout << obj(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

**edit:** it seems like this won't work either without following @mkaes answer, since apparently the definition of the `std::function` depends on it.