# variadic template - error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

In my C++ project I just created a .h file, this is exactly what the file is:

```
    template <typename... ParamTypes>   
    void setTimeOut(int milliseconds,ParamTypes... parames)
    {
    };
```

When I compile it it gives me two errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'          settimeout.h
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ParamTypes'           settimeout.h
```

without this file, there is no errors when I compile the project.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp) could help? VS2012 by default does not support variadic templates.

Comment: What is this C++11x you speak of? :-) And support for variadic templates was added in VS2012 November CTP. You need to have that installed, or upgrade to VS2013.

Comment: sorry, it is supposed to be C++11. BTW, my visual stuido is VS2012 November CTP.

Comment: Sorry guys, I found the solution at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp

Comment: @Giswin - FYI you should be able to mark your own response as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the convenience if somebody has the same problem. I found the solution at:

[Variadic Template in VS 2012 (Visual C++ November 2012 CTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp)