# template <class ... Args> void operator()( Args && ... args ) shows compile error "Class" missing tag

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I was trying to compile a library in visual studio 2012 which is originally written for visual studio 2015 in c++. I have an error saying **'class' missing tag**.

Screen shoot of error msg
[image]

Code of the class for which it is showing compile error.

```
template <class T>
class construct
{
   public:
      template <class ... Args>
      void operator()( Args && ... args );
      T * operator->()
      {
         if( !itsValid )
            throw Exception("Object must be initialized prior to accessing members");

         return itsPtr;
       } 

       T * ptr()
       {
           return operator->();
       }

   private:
      template <class A, class B> friend struct ::cereal::memory_detail::LoadAndConstructLoadWrapper;

      construct( T * p ) : itsPtr( p ), itsValid( false ) {}
      construct( construct const & ) = delete;
      construct & operator=( construct const & ) = delete;

      T * itsPtr;
      bool itsValid;
};
```

This issue might occured due to different version of C++ compiler. Visual studio 2012 uses C++0x and Visual studio 2015 uses C++11.

Any suggestion how to compile it Visual Studio 2012 is highly appreciated.

Comment: C++11 implementation is very spotty and almost unusable in VS2012, and marginal in VS2013. In general back-porting C++11 code is a Sysiphean task. [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238408/variadic-template-in-vs-2012-visual-c-november-2012-ctp) may be of some help though.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are experiencing is most like the result of using variadic templates in your code: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

A trip to MSDN shows that they first show up in VS 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779(v=vs.120).aspx

You are setting yourself up for a long haul if you have to strip out language constructs to downgrade compilers.